# How to avoid overlap between pages of firebase query results

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am trying to implement infinite scroll (aka paging) using Firebase's relatively new query functionality.  I am stuck on one hopefully minor issue.

I ask for the first 10 results as follows:

```
    offersRef.queryOrderedByChild(orderedByChildNamed).queryLimitedToFirst(10).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, andPreviousSiblingKeyWithBlock:childAddedBlock, withCancelBlock:childAddedCancelBlock)
```

But when I want to get the next 10, I will have to start with the 10th key as my starting value.  What I *really* want is to pass the 10th key and tell firebase that I want it offset by 1, so that it will observe the next 10.  But I think "offset" is old syntax (before query functionality was rolled out) and can't be used here.

So I tried asking for 11 and then ignoring the first one, but that is problematic as you may quickly guess, since the results I am observing can (and will) change:

```
    offersRef.queryOrderedByChild(orderedByChildNamed).queryStartingAtValue(startingValue,childKey:startingKey!).queryLimitedToFirst(10+1).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, andPreviousSiblingKeyWithBlock:childAddedBlock, withCancelBlock:childAddedCancelBlock)
```

And just for clarity, the following are all variables defined in my app and not particularly germane to the question:

offersRef
orderedByChildNamed
childAddedBlock
childAddedCancelBlock

Comment: I'm not detecting a question here. You've stated the limitations of the system quite succinctly. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/AgBN7/) for a rudimentary paging implementation. Check out [this branch](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util/tree/v2-paginate/src/Paginate/libs) for an upcoming, more sophisticated solution.

Comment: Sorry, Kato.  The question is in the title of the post.  I didn't restate the question in the body of the post, so I apologize for the confusion.  But I realized that using queryStartingAtValue just isn't a good approach.  In my new approach I am using queryLimitedToFirst(n), and then replacing it with queryLimitedToFirst(2n) and so on.  Of course there are some additional mechanics in there, like keeping track of what I've already added as well as ensuring I am not observing multiple times.